# Unable to install gos/react-amqp

Tags: symfony, composer-php

**Context**

I am new to websockets, and trying to implement a notifications pusher on Symfony with the help of the WebsocketBundle, following [this tutorial](https://github.com/GeniusesOfSymfony/WebSocketBundle/blob/master/Resources/docs/Pusher.md).

The bundle is implementing 3 different pushers :

- I tried using the zmq pusher and it just [does not seem to fit with Windows](https://github.com/GeniusesOfSymfony/WebSocketBundle/issues/159) (I am getting the exact same symptoms as in the linked post)
- I then tried WebSocketPusher and when I run the WSServer the port I configured in `config.yml` is not even opening. Same symptom as [this open issue](https://github.com/GeniusesOfSymfony/WebSocketBundle/issues/192)
- So, finally, I tried to use AMQP pusher and this time I cannot even install it, but as my google searches do not end up in github open issues, I think that I'm probably the one missing something here, and thus I'm posting here.

**Problem**

I installed the php extension and it does seem to work as it appears in my php extensions and does not give any errors.

When I run the following command from the tutorial : `composer require gos/react-amqp` I am getting the following response :

```
$ composer require gos/react-amqp
Using version ^0.1.2 for gos/react-amqp
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Can only install one of: evenement/evenement[v2.0.0, v2.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: evenement/evenement[v2.1.0, v2.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: evenement/evenement[v2.0.0, v2.1.0].
    - gos/react-amqp v0.1.2 requires evenement/evenement ~2.0.0 -> satisfiable by evenement/evenement[v2.0.0].
    - Installation request for gos/react-amqp ^0.1.2 -> satisfiable by gos/react-amqp[v0.1.2].
    - Installation request for evenement/evenement (locked at v2.1.0) -> satisfiable by evenement/evenement[v2.1.0].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I don't fully understand the composer error message, but it seems that he is trying to install `evenement/evenement ~2.0.0` and for some reason, it fails.

So I tried to add it manually in the `composer.json`, and `composer install` ran fine, and `evenement/evenement: ~2.0.0` ended up in my `composer.lock` file.

But the `composer require gos/react-amqp` command still gave me the same error message.

Same results after a `composer update` attempt.

Could anyone explain me what is going on ?

I am running PHP 5.5 on a WAMP Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so I finally got it working.

For some reason composer would keep using the 2.1.0 version when it was never required.

For those running into the same kind of composer error, here is what I did :

- `rm composer.lock`
- explicitely ask for the exact minimum required version, in my case : `composer require evenement/evenement:2.0` You should see something like `Updating evenement/evenement (v2.1.0 => v2.0.0) Downloading: 100%` in the console
- `composer install`